# How to relocate the bfd size symbols?

Tags: ld, binutils, bfd

When embedding binary files in a elf image with gcc, is there a way to change the address of the automatically generated `_binary_*_size` symbols? Unlike the `_binary_*_start` and `_binary_*_end` symbols, the `_binary_*_size` symbols don't seem to follow the base address of the code. They are in a bfd absolute section (`*ABS*`).

For example:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -nostdlib -Wl,-Ttext=0x80000000,--format=binary,foo.bin,--format=default boot.S
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm a.out | sort
00000010 A _binary_foo_bin_size
80000000 T _start
80008004 D _binary_foo_bin_start
80008014 D _binary_foo_bin_end
80008014 A __bss_start
80008014 A __bss_start__
80008014 A __bss_end__
80008014 A _bss_end__
80008014 A _edata
80008014 A _end
80008014 A __end__
```

I would like `_binary_foo_bin_size` to be in `0x80008***` instead of `0x00000***`.
(Preferably without writing my own linker script or using extra objcopy commands.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the _size symbol records the size of the section.  So, offsetting this symbol would be wrong -- it would no longer record the size.

I'm curious why you need to do this.  You didn't say.  Maybe there is some other way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I need to get rid of the _size symbols, because when I load the ELF on my board, the debugger is trying to write the _size data at address 0x00000010 which the boot ROM on my board.

Comment: Also I'm surprised there is any data to write.  I guess I would start by more directly trying to remove the symbol.

Comment: That's ARM DS-5 5.16 (with DSTREAM).